# check proof that $B[a,b]$ is not seperable

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

This is what I have to prove:

prove that metric space $B[a,b]$, $a<b$ is not separable. Where $B[a,b]$ is the set of all bounded and defined functions on $[a,b]$, with the metric $d(x,y)=\sup_{t\in[a,b]}|x(t)-y(t)|$. Everything here works in the real numbers by the way.

My attempt:

Take set $S$ the subset of $B[a,b]$ of all functions on $[a,b]$ s.t. every element of $S$ is $1$ on exactly one point in $[a,b]$ and $0$ everywhere else. Then there are uncountably many of those functions (because $[a,b]$ is uncountable). And if $x,y\in S$ two distinct elements, then $d(x,y)=1$. So if we take a ball of radius $\frac 1 3$ around each element of $S$ then we have uncountably many disjoint subsets of $B[a,b]$. 
Assume there is a countable and dense subset $M$ of $B[a,b]$, then it must have an element in each of those balls. But because the balls are disjoint, every element of $M$ is in at most $1$ ball. So M cannot be countable, a contradiction. So $B[a,b]$ is not separable.

Now this is my first proof of this kind so I would appreciate it if someone could tell me if this is correct.
I have seen other non-separability proofs, which work in essentially the same way: constructing an uncountable set of disjoints subsets of the space, so this is what I tried to do there.

Comment: Seems correct to me, the only thing - you need an uncountable set of disjoint *open* subsets in general. Here you have them, of course as they are balls.

Comment: I quote: "But if there is a countably dense subset of $B[a,b]$  then it must have an element in each of those balls, which is impossible". This is correct, but you should justify it. Why can't each element of the "countably dense subset" not belong to an uncountable number of the balls you defined?

Comment: @Jean-PierreMerx Oke I updated it. I think this should be enough right?

Comment: Looks perfect! Sorry to be fussy sometimes.